# SQL trying to use text and date in the same select result column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm doing the following query

```
SELECT 
  IIF( (itemType = 1 OR itemType = 2), 'NA', CONVERT (DATE, createdAt)) AS 'date',
  itemType AS 'type',
  bar AS 'anything'
FROM table1
```

I expect to get something like

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
|  date      |  type   | anything  |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 2019-01-01 |    0    |  blah     |
| NA         |    1    |  blah     |
| 2019-02-15 |    0    |  blah     |
| 2018-08-10 |    0    |  blah     |
| NA         |    2    |  blah     |
|            |    0    |  blah     |
+------------+---------+-----------+
```

but I get following error

```
Error converting date and/or time from character string [SQL State=S0001, DB Errorcode=241]
```

If I change the `'NA'` in the `IIF` clause then I get date of `1900-01-01` in the date column where it should be empty.

So I see the result column of the select is a `datetime` formatted column

Is it possible to place an `'NA'` string instead the date?

PD: I need to do this `CONVERT (DATE, createdAt)` in order to export the date in the expected format when downloaded from the webpage.

PD2: there are items without date, so I need to display Null when there is no date and 'NA' when itemType is 1 or 2

Comment: Handle the conversion in the presentation side and return NULLs from the database. A column can only have one type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have a string `'NA'` and a DATE datetype at the same time

my suggestion use a very large date or use `NULL` istead of `NA`

```
SELECT 
  IIF( (itemType = 1 OR itemType = 2), CONVERT (DATE, '9999-1-1')), CONVERT (DATE, createdAt)) AS 'date',
```

OR

```
SELECT 
  IIF( (itemType = 1 OR itemType = 2), 'NA', CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(createdAt AS DATE), 105)) AS 'date',
```

Comment: I need to show a 'Not Applicable' text ('NA') instead empty or NULL

Comment: Then return the `createdAt`  as text instead of `DATE` type. You cant have DATE and TEXT on the same column

Comment: As simple as this... convert the datetime to varchar. It works. If you propose it as a solution I will accept it.   `CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(createdAt AS DATE), 105)`

Comment: I made the change, but I thought createdAt was string so no need to change data type

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT 
  case when itemType in(1,2) then 'NA' else cast(createdAt as date) end AS 'date',
  foo AS 'something',
  bar AS 'anything'
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `NULL` instead of 'NA'

```
SELECT 
  IIF( (itemType = 1 OR itemType = 2), NULL, CONVERT (DATE, createdAt)) AS 'date',
  itemType AS 'type',
  bar AS 'anything'
FROM table1
```

Comment: I need to show a 'Not Applicable' text ('NA') instead empty or NULL

Comment: You cannot have a string 'Not Applicable' and a DATE datetype at the same time in a column

Comment: Missing dates are usually stored as NULL in datefields, and when you Select it for any reporting you could use ISNULL(DateColumn,'Not Applicable') for user convenience